# Why is my custom Tailwind CSS utility not applying to React elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create multiple themes by following this: https://github.com/adamwathan/theming-tailwind-demo

My code:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    backgroundColor: {
      primary: "var(--color-bg-primary)",
    },
    textColor: {
      primary: "var(--color-text-primary)",
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
// tailwind.css
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

.theme-TCD {
  --color-bg-primary: #411218;

  --color-text-primary: #e8982e;
}
```

```
// My HTML
<div className="theme-TCD">
  <div className="bg-primary">
    <Banner />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried "color-bg-primary" and "backgroundColor-primary" in place of "bg-primary" but that does not work.

Comment: FYI, Your CSS should be placed before `@tailwind utilities;` and maybe before `@tailwind components;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CRA(Create React App)? If so, you'll have to do some setup.

First, you'll need to install some dependencies

```
yarn add -D tailwindcss autoprefixer postcss-cli
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev tailwindcss autoprefixer postcss-cli
```

After you'll need to create a `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to add some scripts to compile the styles

```
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    //... place these after the four scripts created by CRA
    "build:styles": "postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css", 
    "prebuild": "yarn build:styles",
    "prestart": "yarn build:styles"
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    //... place these after the four scripts created by CRA
    "build:styles": "postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:styles",
    "prestart": "npm run build:styles"
  }
}
```

Source: [Setting up Tailwind With create-react-app](https://dev.to/hagnerd/setting-up-tailwind-with-create-react-app-4jd)

Comment: I follow the article you linked and I was able to get it to work with yarn. In my project, I originally followed this tutorial with npm: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/tailwindcss-react-project/. Why does that not work?

Comment: I've looked at the article and they appear to have similar steps. Could it be that you may have mixed something up?

@TonyZheng since the answer helped you, could you mark it as the answer and upvote it?

Comment: Okay I spoke too soon. I saw that text-primary was applying, but bg-primary doesn't.